# Android app giving network error when connecting to a database

Tags: android, database, mongodb, react-native, android-studio

I have a react native app that fetches books from a database and displays them. It works fine on iOS when the mongodb backend is running, but not on android. I just get a network error as shown below.

[image]

Do any of you know how to fix it?
Here is my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />s
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="29" android:minSdkVersion="16" tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react"/>
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" />
</manifest>
```

Please let me know how to fix this.
Thanks.

(Please let me know in the comments if you need to see any frontend or backend files.)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue and thought the solution might help someone else. All that was happening was that the emulator was not getting localhost. To fix this, in my front end, I replaced localhost:3000 with 10.0.2.2:3000. It fixed the issue.

Instead of

```
.post('http://localhost:3000/login'...
```

it should be

```
.post('http://10.0.2.2:3000/login'...
```

Thanks to @Raghav Herugu for helping me solve the problem